# Assigning additional labeled aliases to a single physical network interface for IPv6 addresses

Tags: networking, 14.04, interface, ipv6

Currently I am stuck trying to label the interfaces for additional IP addresses I am adding to an interface. Let's say the interface is eth0 (`$IFACE`), then for `$ADDRFAM="inet"` I can add an IPv4 address to a labeled alias of `eth0` like this:

```
ip -f $ADDRFAM addr add 10.0.0.1 dev $IFACE:test label $IFACE:test
```

which translates to

```
ip -f inet addr add 10.0.0.1/32 dev eth0:test label eth0:test
```

where the `-f inet`, i.e. IPv4, is implied and could be left out.

A cursory check with `ifconfig` yields:

```
eth0:test Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Trying something similar with IPv6 (`$ADDRFAM="inet6"`):

```
ip -f $ADDRFAM addr add fdbf:98fc:66a5:de67::1/128 dev $IFACE:test label $IFACE:test
```

which expands to

```
ip -f inet6 addr add fdbf:98fc:66a5:de67::1/128 dev eth0:test label eth0:test
```

**indicates no failure, but doesn't yield the expected result either**:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
          [...]
          inet6 addr: fdbf:98fc:66a5:de67::1/128 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5641 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5483 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:792232 (792.2 KB)  TX bytes:861177 (861.1 KB)

eth0:test Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

What gives? Why does the labeling not give the expected effect of listing the address under `eth0:test`?

---

For comparison, the respective lines from `ip addr` look like this:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    [...]
    inet 10.0.0.1/32 scope global eth0:test
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    [...]
    inet6 fdbf:98fc:66a5:de67::1/128 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: You should not be using old-style interface aliases _at all_ anymore, (they contain a colon) despite that there are millions of outdated tutorials out there. All your IP addresses should be directly on the interface.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: why? The documentation states only a single thing about this, that there are old-style (legacy style) aliases and that you can add more `iface ...` blocks to add more addresses (examples only given gor IPv4). Alas, even that doesn't work with IPv6. Not to mention that it prevents me from giving sensible names to the interfaces.

Comment: If you want to rename the interface, then just rename the interface rather than making aliases.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: you do realize that I was asking for different names for the different public IP addresses? Which means I do not merely want to rename the physical interface. In fact I don't care whether that's called `eth0` or `em1` or whatever. What I am interested is to group the public IPv4/IPv6 pairs into aliases of meaningful names. But you made a claim and still haven't provided any reasons. Also: this clearly indicates that the examples *coming with Ubuntu* as well as the `man` pages *in Ubuntu* are equally outdated as the ominous tutorials you're referring to (which I haven't seen).

Answer (score 1):

I realize this answer is for different flavors of 'NIX but I'll take a second stab and see if this helps.

Q. How do I add multiple IPv6 address to eth0 under Red Hat / Fedora / RHEL / CentOS Linux for virtual hosting?

A. There are two ways to add network aliaes under Red hat / CentOS Linux system. You need to edit any one of the following file in order to add IPv6 network alias.

```
/etc/rc.local - Use ifconfig command and shell loop.
/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 - Set special variable called IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES for eth0 virtual hosting (network alias).
```

First, setup IPv6 main server IP address and default router. Once basic IPv6 connectivity established you can setup aliases for NIC.
/etc/rc.local configuration

To add 2607:f0d0:1002:11::10 to 2607:f0d0:1002:11::50 (total 40) virtual aliases, open /etc/rc.local file, enter:

## vi /etc/rc.local

Append following code:

## IP Alias

for ip in {10..40}; do /sbin/ifconfig eth0 inet6 add 2607:f0d0:1002:11::${ip}/64; done

You can type the same command at a shell prompt to immediately activate network aliases. Or create a shell script and call it from /etc/rc.local itself:

## !/bin/bash

INETP="2607:f0d0:1002:11::"
PRE="64"
START=2
END=200
INT_IF="eth0"
IFCONFIG=/sbin/ifconfig
echo -n "Adding IPv6 Alias..."
for i in {$START..$END}
do
  $IFCONFIG $INT_IF inet6 add ${INETP}${i}/${PRE}
done
echo "Done!"

sysv style configuration

Open network interface configuration file, enter:

## vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

Append a list of secondary IPv6 addresses following code (set 5 aliases):

IPV6ADDR_SECONDARIES="2607:f0d0:1002:11::10/64 \
2607:f0d0:1002:11::11/64 \
2607:f0d0:1002:11::12/64 \
2607:f0d0:1002:11::13/64 \
2607:f0d0:1002:11::14/64"

Save and close the file. Restart networking:

## /etc/init.d/network restart

So it seems the IPV6 address is an alias in and of itself.

source: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redhat-centos-rhel-fedora-linux-add-multiple-ip-samenic/

Comment: I think you are mixing up concepts, due to the similar name! Please read that man page yourself first. Of course I will be happy if you can point out how this connects to what I am trying to do. Also see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3484.txt ... this is what `ip-addrlabel` is all about.

Comment: @0xC0000022L my apologies I obviously have no idea what you are trying to do. Perhaps you could elaborate? Thank you

Comment: Try to follow the `:test` (or `eth0:test`) in the commands and outputs inside my question. The address label your answer is about is in a sense related precedence ("address selection"), not to labeling as in "naming". I am trying to *name* the interfaces (and aliases) in IPv6 as I can do in IPv4.

Comment: Does this help? http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/x1035.html.

Comment: Or this? http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ip.htm

Comment: as you can see from the output of `ip addr` and `ifconfig` in my question, the IP addresses are added. However, the behavior with names/labels differs between IPv4 and IPv6 and I'd like to achieve the same that works with IPv4 also with IPv6.